# Не работает корректно редактирование студента

Tags: java, mysql, spring, java-ee

Я хочу в своем проекте на JSP странице "editstudent.jsp" сделать возможноть изменять фио и аватарку студента. Вроде все написала правильно но он ничего не изменяет, фио и аватарка остаются такими какими были раньше

Student Service

```
public interface StudentService {

    List<Student> getAllStudents();

    Student getStudentById(Long id);

    boolean saveStudent(Student student);

    boolean deleteStudentById(Long id);

    File loadAvatarByFileName(String filename);

    File saveAvatarImage(MultipartFile avatarImage) throws IOException;

        Student updateStudent(String name, String surname, MultipartFile avatar, Student targetStudent) throws IOException;
}
```

Student Service Impl

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Value("${storage.location}")

    private String storageLocation;

    private StudentRepository repository;

    public StudentServiceImpl() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentServiceImpl(StudentRepository repository) {
        super();
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        repository.findAll().forEach(e -> list.add(e));
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudentById(Long id) {
        Student student = repository.findById(id).get();
        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveStudent(Student student) {
        try {
            repository.save(student);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteStudentById(Long id) {
        try {
            repository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override

    public File loadAvatarByFileName(String filename) {

        return new File(storageLocation + "/" + filename);

    }

    @Override


    public File saveAvatarImage(MultipartFile avatarImage) throws IOException {

        File newFile = File.createTempFile(
                avatarImage.getName(),
                "." + avatarImage.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[1],

                new File(storageLocation));

        avatarImage.transferTo(newFile);

        return newFile;

    }

    @Override

    public Student updateStudent(String name, String surname, MultipartFile avatar, Student targetStudent)

           throws IOException {

        if (name != null && !name.equals(targetStudent.getName())) {

            targetStudent.setName(name);

        }

        if (surname != null && !surname.equals(targetStudent.getSurname())) {

            targetStudent.setSurname(surname);

        }

        String oldAvatarName = targetStudent.getAvatar();

        if (oldAvatarName != null) {
            Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(storageLocation + File.separator + oldAvatarName));
        }

        File newAvatar = null;
        if (avatar != null) {
            newAvatar = saveAvatarImage(avatar);
            assert newAvatar != null;
            targetStudent.setAvatar(newAvatar.getName());
        }

       boolean isSaved = saveStudent(targetStudent);

        if (!isSaved) {

            throw new IOException();

        }

        Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(storageLocation + File.separator + oldAvatarName));

        return targetStudent;

    }


}
```

Student repository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long>{

}
```

Student Controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
            @RequestParam("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/error";
        }

        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }
```

Edit Student JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <center>
                <h1>${headerMessage}</h1>


                <form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editStudent" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table>
                        <input type="hidden" value="${student.id}" name="id"/>
                        <tr>

                            <td><label path="Name">Name</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="${student.name}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Surname">Surname</label></td>
                            <td><input name="surname" value="${student.surname}"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Avatar">Avatar:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/avatar?avatar=${student.avatar}"
                                     style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="file" name="avatar"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form:form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

И в логе заметил ошибку

```
C:\Pictures\avatar3435295369309803118.jpg: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.
```

Avatar Controller

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class AvatarController {

    @Value("${storage.location}")
    private String storageLocation;

    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    @Autowired
    public AvatarController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/avatar")
    public void getAvatar(HttpServletResponse response, @Param("avatar") String avatar) throws IOException {
        if (avatar == null || avatar.isEmpty()) {

            return;

        }

        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(studentService.loadAvatarByFileName(avatar)), response.getOutputStream());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void image(@RequestParam String url, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(url);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете приводить только тот код, который непосредственно связан с проблемой? Т.е., только те части кода, которые взаимодействуют с картинкой(например, только отдельные методы, а не целые классы). Ну и маппинг можете оставить.

Comment: Я добавил Аватар контроллер

Comment: Просто я сидел на зарубежных форумах там просто просят весь код отправить, чтобы было понятно)